# Qtip2 as contextmenu not showing on Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, qtip, right-click

Environment: 
- jquery 1.9.1
- qtip2: 2.0.1-35

I encounter a weird issue with the opening of a qtip2 binded for right click (as a contextmenu replacement, following [official tutorial](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/tutorials/events/) to do so).

On firefox, all goes well and the contextmenu shows up as soon as I right-click the target element.
On Chrome, for reason unknown, I have to left click then right click the target to get the qtip work.

[My test environment](https://www.zebramanager.com/test.html)

The weird thing is that it works properly on both browsers with this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/PaQ7R/10/

with exactly the same source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
      <script src="jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.qtip.css">
  <style type='text/css'>
        ul#candMenu {
            display: none;
        }
  </style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(document).on("mousedown", ".test", function(event) {
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: $("#candMenu").clone()
            },
            show: {
                event: "mouseup",
                ready: true, 
                solo: true
            },
            hide: {
                event: "unfocus" // Si qqchose d autre que le tooltip est cliqué
            },
            position: {
                my: "left top",
                target: "mouse", // Position it where the click was...
                adjust: { mouse: false }, // ...but dont follow the mouse
                viewport: $(window) // empêche le débordement de la fenêtre
            },
            events: {
                show: function(eventShow, api) {
                    if(eventShow.originalEvent.which !== 3) {
                        eventShow.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, event);
    }).bind("contextmenu", function() { return false; });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="javascript:;" class="test">Test right click</a><br />
  <a href="javascript:;">No-test</a>

<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr class="test">
        <td>prem</td>
        <td>seco</td>
        <td>third</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
        <td>prem</td>
        <td>seco</td>
        <td>third</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<UL id="candMenu">
    <LI class="event separator"><A href="javascript:;">Événements<SPAN class="holdctrl"></SPAN></A></LI>
        <LI class="edit"><A href="javascript:;">Infos du candidat<SPAN class="holdctrl"></SPAN></A></LI>
        <LI class="permis"><A href="javascript:;">Demande de permis<SPAN class="holdctrl"></SPAN></A></LI>
        <LI class="prod"><A href="javascript:;">Produits<SPAN class="holdctrl"></SPAN></A></LI>
        <LI class="regle"><A href="javascript:;">Règlements<SPAN class="holdctrl"></SPAN></A></LI>
        <LI class="form"><A href="javascript:;">Formation<SPAN class="holdctrl"></SPAN></A></LI>
</UL>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried also in an non SSL environment and same strange behaviour.
I can't find if there's a trick on fiddle environment or a misconfiguration on my server to explain that difference.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by re-installing Chrome after deleting all files related to it in user profile.